# How many Bitcoins existed when block 209,999 was mined?

Tags: blockchain

[This article](http://mineforeman.com/2012/11/30/dissecting-bitcoin-block-210000/) claims `there are now 10,499,925 bitcoin` (at the time of the reward drop from 50 to 25).

Weren't there supposed to be exactly 21,000,000 / 2 = 10,500,000 BTC mined at this point? What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suppose this is the [culprit](https://blockexplorer.com/block/00000000000743f190a18c5577a3c2d2a1f610ae9601ac046a38084ccb7cd721). If we add the duplicate 50BTC that is missing and the first reward from block 21,000,000, we would have 10,500,000BTC in total.

However, my calculations would be: 21000000 blocks (ranging from Genesis Block ***0***, to block 20,999,999) multiplied by 50 BTC, that would give us 10,500,000
With the duplicate transaction, that would be 10,499,950 BTC total.

Comment: IIRC there's another duplicate as well. If the OP's number is actually for block #210,000, this accounts for it.

Comment: What is a duplicate transaction? How does it make some bitcoins invalid? Is there a thread that discusses this?

Comment: @ripper234 - This - http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/3030/two-blocks-two-transactions-same-hash

Comment: The output of the genesis block cannot be spent.

Comment: @PieterWuille Hmm, that's interesting. Any reason for that?

Comment: Nobody knows, and there is no explicit comment about it in Satoshi's source code. However, no full node to date would allow him to spend it. Perhaps it was deliberate.